# How do I use dictation and play my music in iTunes on my Mac at the same time?

Tags: macos, audio, voice-dictation, sonoma

How do I use dictation and play my music in iTunes on my iMac running macOS Sonoma 14.3.1 at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

It’s not feasible.

To use dictation, you need a quiet background environment: [If your Mac doesn’t recognize text and commands you speak](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mac-recognize-text-commands-speak-mh40627/13.0/mac/13.0).

Whether playing music on iTunes simultaneously or playing music on external audio equipment, this will create background “noise” that will interfere with the dictation feature